# module build failed in angular router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Hi I am trying to create a angular project, after creating the project when i gave **ng s** it is throwing the following error. I have deleted the node modules and re installed again, created a new folder and tried again, same error. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance

```
./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: E:\Downloads\SpringBootProjects\AngularNgPrime\client\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary solution could be:

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Add the following lines to your package.json's dependency section:

```
    "@babel/generator": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/parser": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/traverse": "7.22.5",
```

3. Run `npm install`
4. Then `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

it's a global issue that's coming from angular. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50961

Answer (score 0):

Add this to package.json

```
"overrides": {
  "@babel/traverse": "7.22.6"
}
```

delete node_modules

`npm install` & `ng serve`

Comment: Please explain what it does

Answer (score -1):

Yesterday worked fine (after erase package-lock.json and node_modules and run npm i) today I'm getting this problems after same procedure.

> ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module
> build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/http.mjs - Error: Module build
> failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/http.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2022/forms.mjs - Error: Module build
> failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2022/forms.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs
>
> - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module
> build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2022/ng-bootstrap.mjs -
> Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2022/ng-bootstrap.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/fesm2022/ng-select-ng-select.mjs -
> Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/fesm2022/ng-select-ng-select.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/fesm2020/ngx-translate-core.mjs -
> Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/fesm2020/ngx-translate-core.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/angularx-qrcode/fesm2022/angularx-qrcode.mjs - Error:
> Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/angularx-qrcode/fesm2022/angularx-qrcode.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
>
> ./node_modules/ngx-captcha/fesm2020/ngx-captcha.mjs - Error: Module
> build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> TypeError:
> /v1/node_modules/ngx-captcha/fesm2020/ngx-captcha.mjs:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

Answer (score -1):

Not an actual answer, but I've the same issue since this morning, it was working fine yesterday. npm clean cache --force or reinstalling the node_modules doesn't seems to fix it.